# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space problem - Error while merging dex archives

Tags: migration, androidx

I have recently migrated an old project that was built for Android 23(Marshmallow) to Android 29. After successful migration, I was trying to integrate it with Jenkins. When I perform the task 'clean build assembleRelease', it results in a 'Java Heap space' issue. So, I tried performing the same task in Android Studio(Artic Fox-2020.3.1). It again gave me the same exception with a little more detailing - com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives.

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexNectoCARRelease
D8: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:432)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:242)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:57)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:67)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:97)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:63)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:60)
        at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$2(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:200)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:214)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
        at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
        at Version.fakeStackEntry(Version_2.1.62.java:0)
        at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Y.a(SourceFile:78)
        at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:11)
        at com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
        ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.base/java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:61)
        at java.base/java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:349)
        at com.android.tools.r8.ByteBufferProvider.acquireByteBuffer(ByteBufferProvider.java:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.m.b(SourceFile:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.m.c(SourceFile:3)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.m.f(SourceFile:1)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.r.c(SourceFile:59)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(SourceFile:63)
        at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b$$Lambda$1350/0x0000000100d8b840.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1448)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)


> Task :app:mergeExtDexNectoCARRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeExtDexNectoCARRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
```

**Note:** I have already increased the Heap size of the IDE to the maximum(4096 MB) via Settings > Appearance & Behaviour > System Settings > Memory Settings. Also have added org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.parallel=true to gradle.properties file.

Built the project with gradle version 6.8 upon JDK 1.8_281. Also, I tried to upgrade the Gradle version to the latest 7.0.3 which runs upon JDK 11.0.12.

Please help me out, been stuck with this for quite long.

Comment: I now have the same problem with Android Studio Iguana (AGP 8.3.1). Project worked fine before with AS Hedgehog. Did you ever find a solution?